# Woocommerce add action before div in woocommerce_before_main_content

Tags: woocommerce, action

I want to add the `woocommerce_catalog_ordering` action right before my shop-header div. This will add it after my container div. Since my custom html isn't an action like woocommerce has built in, i'm not sure how to order them both.

```
function shop_page_header() {
    get_template_part('elements/header-nav'); 

        remove_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop' , 'woocommerce_catalog_ordering', 30 );
        // Remove the result count from WooCommerce
        remove_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop' , 'woocommerce_result_count', 20 );

    if (is_shop()) { ?>

    <div class="container">
        <?php add_action( 'woocommerce_before_main_content', 'woocommerce_catalog_ordering', 20 ); ?>
        <div class="shop-header">
            <div class="callout">
                <div class="inner">
                    <h4>test</h4>
                    <h1>test</h1>
                    <div class="price">$59.00 - $149.00</div>
                    <h4>test</h4>
                    <a href="" class="btn brown arrow white-arrow">Shop Now</a>
                    <a href="" class="btn white-outline">View More</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <?php }
}

add_action('woocommerce_before_main_content', 'shop_page_header');
```

Answer (score 1):

I restructured things to be like this. I had to break everything up. If there's a better way, please share

```
// shop page header
function shop_page_header() {
    get_template_part('elements/header-nav'); 
}

function shop_page_banner() {

    if (is_shop()) { ?>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="shop-header">
            <div class="callout">
                <div class="inner">
                    <h4>test</h4>
                    <h1>test</h1>
                    <div class="price">$59.00 - $149.00</div>
                    <h4>test</h4>
                    <a href="" class="btn brown arrow white-arrow">Shop Now</a>
                    <a href="" class="btn white-outline">View More</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <?php }
}



remove_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop' , 'woocommerce_catalog_ordering', 30 );
// Remove the result count from WooCommerce
remove_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop' , 'woocommerce_result_count', 20 );

add_action('woocommerce_before_main_content', 'shop_page_header', 10);
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_main_content', 'woocommerce_catalog_ordering', 20 ); 
add_action('woocommerce_before_main_content', 'shop_page_banner', 30);
```

Answer (score 0):

If your theme has the right hook built in you can use the Simply Show Hooks plugin to find the right one:  https://wordpress.org/plugins/simply-show-hooks/